# Copying a LinkedQueue

Tags: java, queue

I am trying to copy the original queue and print out the contents of the queue then run the copy again and print the total number of elements in the queue.  When I run the CopyQueue method on my original queue and use that as input for my ShowQueue method it changes the original queue.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    LinkedUnbndQueue test = new LinkedUnbndQueue();
    test.enqueue('a');
    test.enqueue('b');
    System.out.println( showQueue(CopyQueue(test)) );
    System.out.println( Count(CopyQueue(test)) );

}

public static LinkedUnbndQueue CopyQueue(LinkedUnbndQueue orig){
    LinkedUnbndQueue copy = orig;
    return copy;
}

public static int Count(LinkedUnbndQueue orig){
    int count = 0;
    while(!orig.isEmpty() ){
        orig.dequeue();
        count = count + 1;
    }       
    return count;
}

public static String showQueue(LinkedUnbndQueue orig){
    String str = "";
    while(!orig.isEmpty()){
        str = str + orig.dequeue() + " ";
    }
    return str;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your method CopyQueue is simply wrong. You are using aliasing instead of copying the content of you queue.

When you do:

```
public static LinkedUnbndQueue CopyQueue(LinkedUnbndQueue orig){
  LinkedUnbndQueue copy = orig;
  return copy;
}
```

You are returning a pointer that points to the same orig queue. If you want to copy your queue, you need to copy all elements in a new structure, something like:

```
public static LinkedUnbndQueue CopyQueue(LinkedUnbndQueue orig){
  LinkedUnbndQueue copy = new LinkedUnbndQueue();
  for(Object o : orig){
     copy.add(o);
  }
  return copy;
}
```